# How do I place a slider value in label?

Tags: ios, xcode, uilabel, uislider

I am quite new to Xcode and I am having trouble placing the value of a slider in a label when the slider is value is changed.

Here is my code:
Header file:

```
@interface ViewTwoViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UISlider *slider;
    IBOutlet UILabel *sliderLabel;
}

-(IBAction)sliderValue:(id)sender;
```

and here is my m file:

```
-(IBAction)sliderValue:(UISlider *)sender {
    sliderLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", slider.value];
}
```

I am not 100% sure why the value isn't updating?

I am looking forward to hearing from you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an XCode project that does what you're looking for: http://clrk.it/013r203C1y1F

Note that:

1. The label and slider are hooked up to the `UIViewController` as
   IBOutlets in the storyboard.
2. The slider's `valueChanged`: method is linked to the `UIViewController` in the storyboard.
3. The slider's value is displayed using `%f`.

Your method would look something like this:

```
-(IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(id)sender
{
    if (sender == _slider) {
        _label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.3f", _slider.value];
    }

}
```

Comment: I notived the actions didn't appear when I clicked on my slider, but it did on the project file. So I simply removed my slider, added a new one, added a value changed action and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Here would be my process to figure out the root cause of this problem.

1. Did you remember to connect the `slider` and `sliderLabel` outlets?
2. Did you remember to connect the IBAction to the slider? Set a breakpoint. When you drag the slider, does `sliderValue:` get called?  What are the values of `slider` and `sliderLabel`?
3. Its unusual that your `IBOutlet`s are not properties.  I would expect to see:

`@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *slider;` and

`@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *sliderLabel;`

Comment: The outlets are connected. I will try your code soon and get back to you.  I just called the IBOutlet the way I saw it in a tutorial (except the tutorial changed the label text by a button, not by a slider).

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and seems to be correct..Please check these things:-

1) Have you connected Slider action Value Changed to IBAction method for proper functioning.

2) Check our connections with Outlets.

Hope helps you out..

Comment: What do you mean "Have you connected Slider action Value Changed to IBAction"?

Comment: it means have you connected -(IBAction)sliderValue:(id)sender to value changed or not?

Comment: Thanks for your help.  It wasn't connected, I had to remove the slider, add another slider and connect the sliderValue action (for whatever reason the menu above didn't show). I gave the other guy the answer cause the project example he posted helped a lot!  I appreciate your help though,  thanks! :D