# Update slider value on label when slider animates

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uislider

I am using slider in my app. I have done all the setup only problem i am facing is the label on which i want slider values is not updating. Have a look at my code.
I have a button which on click animates the slider. I am not able to update my label as it shows 0.0 throughout the animation.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
- (IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender
 {
[UIView animateWithDuration:10 animations:^{
        [self.slider setValue:0.0 animated:true];
     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:10 animations:^{
            [self.slider setValue:100.0 animated:true];
        }];
    }];
 }
```

Comment: Are you setting the slider value to the label text?

Comment: Where do you set the text of the label?

Comment: yes ... in - (IBAction)sliderChanged:(id)sender
{
    if (sender == self.slider)
    {
        self.lblSliderValue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.0f", self.slider.value];
    }
}
This only works when i manually move the slider @Bluewings

Comment: Are you sure that `sliderChanged:` method gets called when you animate the slider?

Comment: label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f", self.slider.value];

Comment: @Bluewings Yes 100% sure. But the method never gets called when i click the button. The method works when i slide the slidebar manually.

Comment: @SurajSukale i have it implemented. But its not updating my label. Can you tell me where do i put that piece of code?

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456012/how-do-i-place-a-slider-value-in-label?rq=1) SO answer.

Comment: @Bluewings I have already used that solution in my sliderChanged method and that works smoothly. What i need is "The value must change according to animation on button click." Starts from 0.0 and ends at 100.0 SO i need values to change along with slider animation. And that code i have posted in my question.

Comment: Ok I understand, can you not set the text inside the your animation transition then? So set your label text under the line [self.slider setValue:0.0 animated:true];

Comment: @Devster101 added as you said still its not working :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not working because you try to set the maximum value to the slider so that it is simply set that maximum value with animation nothing more. Try my code that may be help you.

Change your btnClicked with this

```
 - (IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender {
      [self.slider setValue:0 animated:true];
      [self setSliderValue:1];
 }
```

Add this setSliderValue method

```
- (void)setSliderValue:(float)value {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
    [self.slider setValue:value animated:true];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        self.lblSliderValue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.0f", self.slider.value];
        if (self.slider.value != self.slider.maximumValue) {
            [self setSliderValue:value+1];
        }
    }];
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Have you replace your previous code of btnClicked with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
    - (IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender
 {
            [self.slider setValue:0.0 animated:true];
[UIView animateWithDuration:10 animations:^{
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:10 animations:^{
            //[self.slider setValue:100.0 animated:true];
        }];
    }];
 }
```

`sliderChanged` method is like this:

```
 - (void)sliderChanged:(UISlider *)slider {
    self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f", slider.value];
}
```

Comment: Not Working mate :(

Comment: Change one thing put this line [self.slider setValue:0.0 animated:true]; above uiview animation block and remove this line  [self.slider setValue:100.0 animated:true]; from current position to [self.slider setValue:0.0 animated:true]; old position.

Comment: @AjayGabani now the slider stopped. Its not working :(

Comment: @iDeveloper..... set the maximum and minimum value of slider.. also set initial value... then do like above...and check

Comment: @SurajSukale i have done as you said but no success yet. The selector is not being called ! I dont know whats the problem

Comment: @iDeveloper.... did you use this?... sliderOne.continuous=YES; for continuous updating?

Comment: @SurajSukale continuous property will be TRUE by default. value change events are generated any time the value changes due to dragging.

Comment: @SurajSukale it ll be called when the touch on thumbimage is lifted